# Why has Laravel generated a remember_me token for a number of my users when I have never had the remember checkbox present in my login form?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, remember-me

At the request of a client, I have been asked to add a 'remember me' checkbox to the login form on their web app. Easy enough, since Laravel provides this out of the box; and since I pretty much used the boilerplate users table, it already contains this column.

However, in the process of adding this, I have noticed that perhaps as many as one in every twenty users in the live db *already has a remember_me token generated* (all the others are `null` as I would expect).

- I have *never* had a 'remember me' checkbox displayed on the login form.
- I have *never* passed a `remember` variable as part of the login request.

My understanding (partly from the docs/existing forum posts, and partly from experimentation) is:

- The `remember_me` column will be populated with a token if the *remember me* checkbox is selected on the login form (and thus a `true` value for the `remember` request variable is passed to the server and processed by Laravel's default login architecture )
- When the user explicitly logs out, *if* this token exists (i.e. `remember_token` is not null) then it will be regenerated; otherwise it is ignored and the `null` value is left alone.

Assuming my understanding is correct, how have these users that I'm seeing managed to get themselves a remember token in my app..?

Comment: If you only remove the checkbox, it is easy to add the checkbox using the browsers debug bar if the user has the knowledge. But I would think that some users get to the Laravel default login form in some cases. It would surprise me if multiple users would add it manually

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Yeah; they could manipulate the DOM and add it in easily enough I guess if they had that knowledge... but.. why.. how.. *one in every twenty* out of about five thousand users..? :/ Surely there must be something I'm missing here.

Comment: There is also definitely no way they could get to the default login form since I've replaced all the default auth routing and templates

Comment: @Inigo I am not sure but could you check when user forgot their password then laravel sent a reset password link with `token`.  i guess `remeber_token` was used. Can you check that

Comment: @AmitSenjaliya Great suggestion- I think you've got it! Didn't think of that! Yep, just tested, and if they use the password reset link it does indeed replace the `null` value with an auto-generated token. Awesome- many thanks for solving this mystery :) (if you want to add your comment as an answer I'll accept)

Comment: @Inigo It's my pleasure to help you. I think does not need to add a comment as an answer. Thank you very much.